# Pimcore: Get all Assets which name contain a given string via API

Tags: graphql, pimcore

I tried all day long to find a way to get all assets which filename contains a given string via API. Unfortunately without any luck.
I use Pimcore 6.9.6 and the Data-Hub in Version 1.0.8.
It seems like the samples in the data hub docs are not really working. I can't use getAssets and getAssetListing seems to be pretty pointless, since it only returns an empty result.
I hope someone here can point me into the right direction. Thanks in advance for any help.

```json
{
  getAssetListing(filter: "{\"filename\": {\"$like\" :\"%1%\"}}") {
    edges {
      node {
        __typename
        ... on asset {
          fullpath
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This GraphQL query should do the trick, but unfortunately I can't get it working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I missed to fill in the root path for assets in the security tab of the Pimcore Data Hub configuration.